# Black Ops 2 Split Screen with sidebars issue

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

In Call of Duty Black Ops 2, when you split screen on Xbox 360 the screen safe dimensions shrink forcing the game to not take the whole screen. Does anyone know of a method to fix this issue or am I out of luck? Sources appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you see minimap, ammo or weapon bars? if you cant i can help you.

Comment: Yeah it all loads just fine, The safe area just shrinks down to produce a 4:3 effect instead of a 16:9 (using all available space)

Comment: That's the way its supposed to be when you play split screen.

Comment: @user64006 And if I don't want it that way?

Comment: Do you have dual play on your TV? If so, enable it to have fullscreen for both players. If you don't the only way is to stretch it (it won't look good).

Comment: @LameBrains No, I don't but it was just to find out. Surprised this question even had that much attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fix for this. It is the only way to play split screen.